# Cannot find function Split_by in R in purrr package

Tags: r, purrr

I remember using this function split_by before from the package `purrr`. Now when I try to access it, it says could not find cunction `Split_by`. I tried doing an ls on the package `purrr` and I couldnt find the function in there. Is there any alternative that serves the purpose in the package?

Comment: Looks like it is coming to dplyr 8.0 https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse.org/commit/ef3bf15d53483b95e6dbd1e7c02a97bbd0e390a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here for `purrr 0.2.3`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/news.html

> order_by(), sort_by() and split_by() have been removed. order_by()
>   conflicted with dplyr::order_by() and the complete family doesn’t feel
>   that useful. Use tibbles instead (#217).

Here is the original code from purrr `0.2.2`:

```
split_by <- function(.x, .f, ...) {
  vals <- map(.x, .f, ...)
  split(.x, simplify_all(transpose(vals)))
}
```

And the original example:

```
l2 <- rerun(5, g = sample(2, 1), y = rdunif(5, 10))
l2 %>% split_by("g") %>% str()
```

**Using tibbles instead**

I understand the direction "use tibbles instead" this way :

Your list has several items sharing the same structure, thus list is not the appropriate structure, you could convert to a `tibble` to respect the tidy rules of `"one row by observation, one column by variable"`, following previous example:

```
t2 <- as_tibble(transpose(l2)) %>% mutate(g=unlist(g))
```

Then you can split it :

```
split(t2,t2$g)

# $`1`
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#         g         y
#     <int>    <list>
#   1     1 <dbl [5]>
#   2     1 <dbl [5]>
#   3     1 <dbl [5]>
#   
#   $`2`
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#         g         y
#     <int>    <list>
#   1     2 <dbl [5]>
#   2     2 <dbl [5]>
```

Or use `dplyr::group_by` (and keep it cleaner regarding tidy principles) :

```
t2 %>% group_by(g) %>% your_code
```

Comment: I updated with my take on following hadley's recommendations to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

`split_by` was deprecated in version 0.2.3 - see [the release notes](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/releases)

The functionality is now in `pluck`, but you can pass multiple arguments - from the `pluck` docs:

```r
library(purrr)
# pluck() supports integer positions, string names, and functions.
# Using functions, you can easily extend pluck(). Let's create a
# list of data structures:
obj1 <- list("a", list(1, elt = "foobar"))
obj2 <- list("b", list(2, elt = "foobaz"))
x <- list(obj1, obj2)

# And now an accessor for these complex data structures:
my_element <- function(x) x[[2]]$elt

# The accessor can then be passed to pluck:
pluck(x, 1, my_element)
#> [1] "foobar"
pluck(x, 2, my_element)
#> [1] "foobaz"
```